# Add new and update existed object into many-to-many table with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

```
class A
{
    int Id; //Primary key
    string Name;
}

class B
{
    int Id; //Primary key
    string Name;
}

class AB
{
    int Id; //PK
    int AId; //FK
    int BId; //FK
}
```

In this situation:
"A" exists in database
"B" and "AB" are new created objects.

```
A a = new A("asd");
B b = new B("qwe");
AB ab = new AB(1, 1);
```

How should I add this with Entity Framework to database?

Is it something like this? It should be 3 context for each entity?

```
mydb.A.Context.ApplyCurrentValues(a)
mydb.B.Context.AddObject(b)
mydb.AB.Context.AddObject(ab) //connected with A and B above
```

Comment: Are the PKs auto generated or manually entered?

Comment: You should load A from the database instead of re-creating it, and then trying to trick the context into believing it is the existing one in the database. And definitely NOT three contexts, else EF cannot connect them.

Answer (score 2):

In a database first approach, firstly you entity AB unnecessarily has a primary key as its an associative entity only.  Unless you want to hold other attributes on that table a Pk is not necessary and would result in EF 4 creating a separate entity.

Db Diagram of relationship:

[image]

EF edmx result:

[image]

Using that relationship to answer your question.

```
    public void addNewBtoA(B newEntity, A existingEntity) {

        _myContext.Attach(existingEntity);
        existingEntity.B.Add(newEntity);
        myContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

EDIT:

An AB record is automatically created by EF in the Db for the many to many relationship.

EDIT 2:

If entity AB has other properties on it then EF will import it as a separate entity, updating the context would go summing like this:

```
B b = new B {
    Name = "name"
};

AB ab = new AB {

    A = existingA,
    B = b,
    arbitraryProp = "my heart is a fist of blood" 

}

_myContext.Attach(existingA);
_myContext.Add(b);
_myContext.Add(ab);
_myContext.SaveChanges();
```

The order of the add is irrelevant as EF determines the order of insertion based on the model relationships defined in the .edmx.  Remember that attaching `existingA` is only necessary if `existingA` is not currently tracked by the `_myContext` - i.e. if `existingA` was fetched using `_myContext.A.SingleOrDefault()` then it is already attached.

EDIT 3:

```
public void testab() {
            A existingA = new A {
                Name = "test a"
            };

            using (ABEntities context = new ABEntities()) {
                context.A.AddObject(existingA);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }


            using (ABEntities context = new ABEntities()) {
                B newB = new B {
                    Name = "test b"
                };

                context.Attach(existingA);
                existingA.B.Add(newB);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But I need insert also new AB object. What's now?

Comment: @Saint AB entity should not exist. AB is just a table in database.

Comment: @Saint: See edit.  EF maintains the many to many relationship and will create the records in the AB table.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt how to create this model? My edmx contains ProbesChannels class (box)

Comment: Please clarify your comment - i don't understand

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt Ok nevermind. I've got it. Only one question: What if this table AB contains several additional column(properties) ? How should I add new element AB if A and B exists in database?

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt but in this model there's no more AB type. Only A with collection of B, and B with collection of A. Right?

Comment: Yes, but AB will only exist if in the database the AB associative table contains more than just the foreign keys to A and B - my EDIT 2 is describing how to use that scenario.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt Why I get error: "An object with the same key already exists in the objectstatemanager. The objectstatemanager cannot track multiple objects with the same key". NewObject doesn't exist in db

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt I mean yout method: public void addNewBtoA(B newEntity, A existingEntity)

Comment: You going to have to post the rest of you code for me to be able to help.

Comment: see edit 3.  That code i ran and it worked.  Perhaps compare it against yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need modify your `AB` class definition as follows

```
class AB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
AB ab = new AB { A = a, B = b };

// if 'a' is not attached call mydb.A.Attach(a);
mydb.AB.AddObject(ab);
```

EF will figure out the insertion order of the entities.

Comment: I get error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Comment: you don't need an AB class. You should add have a `public virtual IList<A> AList {get;set;}` in B class and a `public virtual<B> BList {get;set;}` in A class

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus If the database schema can be changed that's the better solution.